# Sh скрипт сравнения файлов, возможно?

Tags: shell

с помощью какой команды можно организовать сравнение файлов? find? grep?а точнее сравнение слепков, мол прошелся сделал слепок вида:

имя_файла,размер,дата

а потом уже сравниваешь по новой, текущее состояние, с тем что записано.цель всего этого - выявить новые файлы, а также те которые были изменены.

если предложите вариант проще или дадите направление, в котором копать будет круто)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов масса. Вот первый пришел в голову:

```
 find /tmp/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > /home/user/tmp.md5 echo "123" > /tmp/newfile find /tmp/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > /home/user/tmp.md5.new cat /home/user/tmp.md5.new /home/user/tmp.md5 | sort | uniq -u d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /tmp/newfile
```

Это на вскидку. А так можно хоть рсинком сравнивать :)

Comment: а что за рсинк?

Comment: rsyncвот тут есть примерны использования http://www.opennet.ru/tips/info/1768.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Если

```
цель всего этого - выявить новые файлы, а также те которые были изменены.
```

то есть же

```
find . -mtime 1
```

покажет все файлы/папки, изменённые за последние сутки, в *man find* все подробности.

Comment: а если у файла будет дата подменена, то такой файл он не увидит, как увидеть его?

Comment: Что значит "подменена"? Это реально? Я имею ввиду в данной ситуации.

Comment: Да, цель вообще всего этого спалить вирусы. у меня например были случаи ломали автоматом сайты на вордпрес и сидели файлы созданные в далеком 2011 году. хотя по логам сломано было в июле.

Answer (score 0):

diff если нужно найти расхождения в примерно одинаковых файлах.

Answer (score 0):

[rkhunter](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/) вам в помощь.

Comment: Это если вам надо вирусы найти.